# How to fit a model with lagged variables

Tags: time-series, lags

I am trying to fit a model with lagged variables.

The problem is: In a big classroom with windows open, the outside temperature, humidity and solar activity will lead to variation in the concentration of pollutants. However, the effects is delayed.

What a model should I try to fit if I want to analyze the delayed effects?

I am trying to analyze the time lag between dependent and independent variables using R command `LagReg`, and get the indication from the beta coefficient. Does this method make sense?

By selecting the lagged variable, I tried to do a multivariate regression model between pollutant concentration and those lagged predictors. Is it OK to do this? Are there better ways to try?

The data is like:

```
Date    con.    T   RH  Airflow
1-Jun-07    51  27  51  529
2-Jun-07    .   28  48  535
3-Jun-07    49  24  60  390
4-Jun-07    42  19  62  225
5-Jun-07    37  17  51  139
6-Jun-07    44  19  44  228
7-Jun-07    76  28  42  494
8-Jun-07    79  26  51  559
9-Jun-07    35  22  43  345
10-Jun-07   28  23  39  413
11-Jun-07   35  25  38  481
12-Jun-07   37  26  41  515
13-Jun-07   .   .   .   .
14-Jun-07   .   28  41  585
15-Jun-07   .   26  40  524
16-Jun-07   .   28  37  548
17-Jun-07   .   28  49  651
18-Jun-07   .   28  51  599
19-Jun-07   .   25  56  589
20-Jun-07   .   23  42  424
21-Jun-07   .   25  44  485
22-Jun-07   .   23  42  425
23-Jun-07   .   20  54  287
24-Jun-07   .   .   .   .
25-Jun-07   .   .   .   .
26-Jun-07   .   27  67  597
27-Jun-07   .   25  69  551
28-Jun-07   .   23  77  508
29-Jun-07   .   22  62  390
30-Jun-07   .   23  53  429
1-Jul-07    .   23  46  420
2-Jul-07    .   21  44  354
3-Jul-07    .   24  43  473
4-Jul-07    .   25  59  540
5-Jul-07    .   26  61  508
6-Jul-07    .   26  52  480
7-Jul-07    .   26  47  485
8-Jul-07    .   28  52  607
9-Jul-07    65  28  59  648
10-Jul-07   62  28  62  631
11-Jul-07   .   23  58  373
12-Jul-07   36  22  46  276
13-Jul-07   32  23  48  239
14-Jul-07   46  24  46  376
15-Jul-07   38  24  47  297
16-Jul-07   .   .   .   .
17-Jul-07   .   .   .   .
18-Jul-07   51  26  65  450
19-Jul-07   34  23  66  256
20-Jul-07   25  22  45  178
21-Jul-07   19  22  45  192
22-Jul-07   16  23  42  232
23-Jul-07   20  24  43  281
24-Jul-07   13  25  45  321
25-Jul-07   .   23  56  .
26-Jul-07   20  24  64  317
27-Jul-07   .   25  67  380
28-Jul-07   .   26  68  357
29-Jul-07   .   26  59  377
30-Jul-07   .   27  51  427
31-Jul-07   .   28  50  464
1-Aug-07    .   29  53  546
2-Aug-07    14  29  55  666
3-Aug-07    .   27  58  632
4-Aug-07    .   25  45  420
5-Aug-07    .   25  71  484
6-Aug-07    .   28  72  583
7-Aug-07    .   29  67  656
8-Aug-07    .   30  66  681
9-Aug-07    .   29  69  694
10-Aug-07   28  27  67  656
11-Aug-07   25  27  64  692
12-Aug-07   .   27  62  691
13-Aug-07   .   24  53  592
14-Aug-07   .   23  61  475
15-Aug-07   .   26  67  477
16-Aug-07   .   25  73  355
17-Aug-07   .   24  57  265
18-Aug-07   28  20  49  185
19-Aug-07   29  20  65  188
20-Aug-07   35  22  75  233
21-Aug-07   .   25  74  .
22-Aug-07   .   .   .   .
23-Aug-07   .   28  65  .
24-Aug-07   .   26  70  .
25-Aug-07   35  24  76  587
26-Aug-07   24  22  60  444
27-Aug-07   24  23  61  472
28-Aug-07   35  27  60  559
29-Aug-07   36  28  61  644
30-Aug-07   24  23  67  510
31-Aug-07   .   22  51  .
1-Sep-07    .   23  50  .
2-Sep-07    .   23  51  .
3-Sep-07    .   25  49  .
4-Sep-07    .   27  48  .
5-Sep-07    .   28  49  .
6-Sep-07    .   26  56  .
7-Sep-07    .   26  64  .
8-Sep-07    .   24  78  .
9-Sep-07    .   24  73  .
10-Sep-07   .   23  66  .
11-Sep-07   .   19  55  .
12-Sep-07   .   17  46  .
13-Sep-07   .   20  43  .
14-Sep-07   .   19  45  .
15-Sep-07   .   14  44  .
16-Sep-07   .   15  42  .
17-Sep-07   .   19  42  .
18-Sep-07   .   23  43  .
19-Sep-07   .   .   .   .
20-Sep-07   37  25  54  329
21-Sep-07   37  25  54  352
22-Sep-07   37  24  41  214
23-Sep-07   34  21  40  257
24-Sep-07   47  26  45  399
25-Sep-07   44  26  61  423
26-Sep-07   35  21  67  159
27-Sep-07   .   20  54  .
28-Sep-07   .   18  46  .
29-Sep-07   27  19  42  135
30-Sep-07   35  21  39  178
1-Oct-07    38  21  48  153
2-Oct-07    38  22  52  192
3-Oct-07    31  22  48  197
4-Oct-07    34  23  47  231
5-Oct-07    49  26  58  352
6-Oct-07    47  27  57  345
7-Oct-07    34  28  54  439
8-Oct-07    39  27  51  498
9-Oct-07    26  21  52  367
10-Oct-07   15  11  50  117
11-Oct-07   21  11  54  76
12-Oct-07   28  12  49  77
13-Oct-07   28  11  51  75
14-Oct-07   30  16  47  104
15-Oct-07   36  19  46  172
16-Oct-07   34  21  53  152
17-Oct-07   38  20  54  151
18-Oct-07   51  23  58  259
19-Oct-07   38  15  55  106
20-Oct-07   32  16  44  107
21-Oct-07   31  21  39  174
22-Oct-07   36  19  48  129
23-Oct-07   28  13  52  71
24-Oct-07   30  11  50  71
25-Oct-07   32  11  49  71
26-Oct-07   39  16  48  128
27-Oct-07   41  11  54  78
28-Oct-07   36  9   49  69
29-Oct-07   32  10  45  64
30-Oct-07   37  12  46  74
31-Oct-07   36  14  48  77
1-Nov-07    32  8   46  58
2-Nov-07    29  9   45  64
3-Nov-07    30  10  45  61
4-Nov-07    32  9   46  61
5-Nov-07    33  9   46  61
6-Nov-07    22  4   47  44
7-Nov-07    .   5   46  59
8-Nov-07    .   7   44  63
9-Nov-07    .   6   48  61
10-Nov-07   38  6   51  60
11-Nov-07   36  8   54  70
12-Nov-07   52  14  59  97
13-Nov-07   52  12  52  72
14-Nov-07   52  13  48  77
15-Nov-07   .   .   .   .
16-Nov-07   45  2   50  55
17-Nov-07   41  5   50  58
18-Nov-07   40  5   51  60
19-Nov-07   42  10  55  72
20-Nov-07   60  17  60  99
21-Nov-07   57  11  57  82
22-Nov-07   41  3   53  52
23-Nov-07   44  0   54  53
24-Nov-07   .   0   54  52
25-Nov-07   39  2   53  54
26-Nov-07   42  4   57  54
27-Nov-07   50  1   58  48
28-Nov-07   52  4   59  51
29-Nov-07   54  -1  50  43
30-Nov-07   59  0   51  47
1-Dec-07    49  -2  56  47
2-Dec-07    52  8   56  58
3-Dec-07    58  -2  53  42
4-Dec-07    53  0   54  46
5-Dec-07    47  -4  55  42
6-Dec-07    .   -5  57  44
7-Dec-07    .   0   53  47
8-Dec-07    58  0   53  48
9-Dec-07    58  0   53  48
10-Dec-07   53  1   54  47
11-Dec-07   52  2   55  50
12-Dec-07   58  3   53  49
13-Dec-07   60  2   52  48
14-Dec-07   59  0   52  46
15-Dec-07   .   -1  52  49
16-Dec-07   .   -4  54  37
17-Dec-07   .   -6  57  42
18-Dec-07   53  0   54  45
19-Dec-07   57  -1  53  46
20-Dec-07   54  -2  55  44
21-Dec-07   54  1   54  48
22-Dec-07   53  7   55  56
23-Dec-07   54  0   54  53
24-Dec-07   50  -3  54  41
25-Dec-07   53  1   52  46
26-Dec-07   52  3   51  49
27-Dec-07   51  2   53  49
28-Dec-07   52  2   53  48
29-Dec-07   59  -1  52  45
30-Dec-07   52  0   52  46
31-Dec-07   50  2   52  49
1-Jan-08    .   .   .   .
2-Jan-08    .   .   .   .
3-Jan-08    .   -10 62  38
4-Jan-08    51  -1  53  45
5-Jan-08    50  4   52  52
6-Jan-08    53  12  57  63
7-Jan-08    101 17  55  111
8-Jan-08    81  14  55  92
9-Jan-08    59  4   50  55
10-Jan-08   .   5   53  55
11-Jan-08   .   3   51  55
12-Jan-08   45  3   50  51
13-Jan-08   47  1   52  50
14-Jan-08   55  -3  53  46
15-Jan-08   55  -5  56  45
16-Jan-08   47  -2  55  51
17-Jan-08   .   1   53  51
18-Jan-08   .   -5  57  43
19-Jan-08   .   .   .   .
20-Jan-08   62  -14 70  38
21-Jan-08   47  -6  62  43
22-Jan-08   50  -4  57  43
23-Jan-08   45  -8  61  41
24-Jan-08   48  -12 63  40
25-Jan-08   46  -11 65  42
26-Jan-08   41  -2  58  46
27-Jan-08   48  -3  56  46
28-Jan-08   46  3   54  51
29-Jan-08   53  7   51  68
30-Jan-08   30  -11 64  36
31-Jan-08   43  -7  61  46
1-Feb-08    46  -1  58  50
2-Feb-08    45  0   57  51
3-Feb-08    46  0   57  53
4-Feb-08    48  5   59  57
5-Feb-08    52  7   58  61
6-Feb-08    .   2   56  53
7-Feb-08    47  0   55  52
8-Feb-08    43  2   54  54
9-Feb-08    44  2   53  52
10-Feb-08   35  -12 63  35
11-Feb-08   42  -13 70  40
12-Feb-08   39  -8  66  40
13-Feb-08   .   -7  65  44
14-Feb-08   .   .   .   .
15-Feb-08   .   -2  60  53
16-Feb-08   46  -3  63  59
17-Feb-08   48  7   58  81
18-Feb-08   51  -2  58  53
19-Feb-08   .   .   .   .
20-Feb-08   38  -6  61  55
21-Feb-08   45  -8  64  62
22-Feb-08   .   -2  62  .
23-Feb-08   .   -3  64  .
24-Feb-08   39  -2  60  56
25-Feb-08   39  1   56  62
26-Feb-08   39  0   56  64
27-Feb-08   40  -7  61  57
28-Feb-08   .   -7  64  .
29-Feb-08   .   1   56  .
1-Mar-08    41  0   51  62
2-Mar-08    .   .   .   .
3-Mar-08    67  9   52  110
4-Mar-08    47  -1  54  63
5-Mar-08    46  -2  55  63
6-Mar-08    42  0   53  64
7-Mar-08    47  -2  56  60
8-Mar-08    48  -5  58  57
9-Mar-08    .   -2  56  60
10-Mar-08   48  3   53  65
11-Mar-08   53  0   53  67
12-Mar-08   .   4   49  73
13-Mar-08   68  8   49  86
14-Mar-08   74  11  47  87
15-Mar-08   50  6   47  66
16-Mar-08   52  4   50  72
17-Mar-08   42  2   52  68
18-Mar-08   52  10  55  93
19-Mar-08   43  5   52  69
20-Mar-08   46  4   50  66
21-Mar-08   44  2   51  67
22-Mar-08   43  2   52  65
23-Mar-08   42  1   51  64
24-Mar-08   44  2   52  63
25-Mar-08   52  6   49  68
26-Mar-08   52  8   46  71
27-Mar-08   .   6   47  .
28-Mar-08   49  3   49  62
29-Mar-08   47  3   49  67
30-Mar-08   47  6   51  72
31-Mar-08   70  16  56  119
1-Apr-08    61  7   52  87
2-Apr-08    46  4   49  68
3-Apr-08    49  7   47  79
4-Apr-08    45  7   52  76
5-Apr-08    53  11  46  91
6-Apr-08    .   .   .   .
7-Apr-08    .   .   .   .
8-Apr-08    .   .   .   .
9-Apr-08    .   .   .   .
10-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
11-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
12-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
13-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
14-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
15-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
16-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
17-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
18-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
19-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
20-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
21-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
22-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
23-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
24-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
25-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
26-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
27-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
28-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
29-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
30-Apr-08   .   .   .   .
1-May-08    .   .   .   .
2-May-08    .   .   .   .
3-May-08    .   .   .   .
4-May-08    .   .   .   .
5-May-08    .   .   .   .
6-May-08    .   .   .   .
7-May-08    .   .   .   .
8-May-08    .   .   .   .
9-May-08    .   .   .   .
10-May-08   .   .   .   .
11-May-08   .   .   .   .
12-May-08   .   .   .   .
13-May-08   .   .   .   .
14-May-08   .   .   .   .
15-May-08   .   .   .   .
16-May-08   .   .   .   .
17-May-08   .   .   .   .
18-May-08   .   .   .   .
19-May-08   .   .   .   .
20-May-08   .   .   .   .
21-May-08   .   .   .   .
22-May-08   .   .   .   .
23-May-08   .   .   .   .
24-May-08   .   .   .   .
25-May-08   .   .   .   .
26-May-08   .   .   .   .
27-May-08   .   .   .   .
28-May-08   .   .   .   .
29-May-08   .   .   .   .
30-May-08   .   .   .   .
31-May-08   .   .   .   .
1-Jun-08    .   .   .   .
2-Jun-08    .   .   .   .
3-Jun-08    .   .   .   .
4-Jun-08    .   .   .   .
5-Jun-08    .   .   .   .
6-Jun-08    .   .   .   .
7-Jun-08    .   .   .   .
8-Jun-08    .   .   .   .
9-Jun-08    .   27  58  563
10-Jun-08   .   23  57  290
11-Jun-08   .   26  47  467
12-Jun-08   49  28  50  525
13-Jun-08   40  25  68  438
14-Jun-08   34  25  49  392
15-Jun-08   32  24  48  354
16-Jun-08   28  21  51  221
17-Jun-08   23  19  47  151
18-Jun-08   25  20  45  179
19-Jun-08   25  21  44  243
20-Jun-08   28  25  36  401
21-Jun-08   34  23  52  287
22-Jun-08   .   21  51  225
23-Jun-08   .   21  50  179
24-Jun-08   .   22  48  188
25-Jun-08   .   24  57  258
26-Jun-08   .   25  62  283
27-Jun-08   55  26  63  335
28-Jun-08   44  25  55  310
29-Jun-08   32  21  51  181
30-Jun-08   28  20  42  155
1-Jul-08    30  22  36  247
2-Jul-08    39  25  48  383
3-Jul-08    30  23  56  191
4-Jul-08    27  22  48  177
5-Jul-08    30  23  46  219
6-Jul-08    35  25  49  382
7-Jul-08    .   27  56  428
8-Jul-08    .   27  66  458
9-Jul-08    .   24  54  251
10-Jul-08   35  25  48  371
11-Jul-08   37  26  55  416
12-Jul-08   37  27  64  416
13-Jul-08   26  24  46  242
14-Jul-08   27  24  46  256
15-Jul-08   34  27  46  441
16-Jul-08   .   29  53  536
17-Jul-08   30  29  57  564
18-Jul-08   28  28  53  676
19-Jul-08   25  27  62  551
20-Jul-08   27  27  67  505
21-Jul-08   30  26  69  438
22-Jul-08   27  24  62  352
23-Jul-08   25  23  54  298
24-Jul-08   24  23  45  243
25-Jul-08   26  24  51  295
26-Jul-08   26  26  57  362
27-Jul-08   22  24  47  289
28-Jul-08   23  26  54  351
29-Jul-08   29  28  52  462
30-Jul-08   24  27  59  403
31-Jul-08   18  27  59  404
1-Aug-08    18  26  67  499
2-Aug-08    12  25  57  613
3-Aug-08    12  25  54  563
4-Aug-08    10  24  66  636
5-Aug-08    8   25  73  676
6-Aug-08    13  25  60  507
7-Aug-08    14  23  54  267
8-Aug-08    .   22  50  207
9-Aug-08    13  21  53  222
10-Aug-08   .   19  49  .
11-Aug-08   14  22  50  214
12-Aug-08   18  23  50  257
13-Aug-08   .   23  53  205
14-Aug-08   .   23  54  200
15-Aug-08   14  22  47  194
16-Aug-08   15  23  47  222
17-Aug-08   18  23  47  263
18-Aug-08   20  24  51  329
19-Aug-08   20  25  51  340
20-Aug-08   20  22  41  258
21-Aug-08   .   24  51  370
22-Aug-08   27  27  60  408
23-Aug-08   32  28  56  478
24-Aug-08   25  26  53  328
25-Aug-08   28  21  47  189
26-Aug-08   25  20  42  204
27-Aug-08   28  24  50  319
28-Aug-08   30  24  56  330
29-Aug-08   27  26  54  431
30-Aug-08   22  25  41  369
31-Aug-08   21  26  39  401
1-Sep-08    19  25  37  384
2-Sep-08    20  27  45  410
3-Sep-08    24  27  55  362
4-Sep-08    27  24  64  260
5-Sep-08    26  23  59  200
6-Sep-08    22  22  48  162
7-Sep-08    19  20  50  158
8-Sep-08    21  20  52  168
9-Sep-08    19  17  48  123
10-Sep-08   21  18  42  150
11-Sep-08   30  20  47  252
12-Sep-08   .   23  68  237
13-Sep-08   46  27  61  447
14-Sep-08   36  23  62  271
15-Sep-08   25  19  53  116
16-Sep-08   23  19  47  117
17-Sep-08   29  21  45  197
18-Sep-08   .   20  45  154
19-Sep-08   .   20  43  189
20-Sep-08   28  23  47  249
21-Sep-08   29  23  51  256
22-Sep-08   30  21  52  230
23-Sep-08   28  21  43  265
24-Sep-08   29  23  40  298
25-Sep-08   26  22  38  245
26-Sep-08   22  21  41  179
27-Sep-08   19  22  46  189
28-Sep-08   18  21  50  193
29-Sep-08   19  19  53  140
30-Sep-08   18  15  49  87
1-Oct-08    19  13  46  78
2-Oct-08    19  13  43  80
3-Oct-08    16  13  45  78
4-Oct-08    .   .   .   .
5-Oct-08    .   14  38  .
6-Oct-08    .   16  40  .
7-Oct-08    .   17  45  .
8-Oct-08    .   16  55  95
9-Oct-08    24  16  42  91
10-Oct-08   24  16  32  110
11-Oct-08   27  20  38  222
12-Oct-08   29  22  37  238
13-Oct-08   31  24  39  224
14-Oct-08   24  20  46  125
15-Oct-08   .   18  53  130
16-Oct-08   22  14  46  77
17-Oct-08   17  13  43  73
18-Oct-08   17  12  40  70
19-Oct-08   16  11  40  67
20-Oct-08   20  13  41  79
21-Oct-08   19  9   42  60
22-Oct-08   20  6   43  57
23-Oct-08   21  9   41  63
24-Oct-08   22  11  49  69
25-Oct-08   22  8   50  60
26-Oct-08   23  9   45  61
27-Oct-08   21  4   49  51
28-Oct-08   21  3   51  49
29-Oct-08   .   5   44  56
30-Oct-08   14  8   42  60
31-Oct-08   25  15  39  94
1-Nov-08    24  15  43  80
2-Nov-08    26  15  44  78
3-Nov-08    31  18  38  98
4-Nov-08    27  17  36  91
5-Nov-08    25  17  36  91
6-Nov-08    31  17  37  99
7-Nov-08    23  12  41  70
8-Nov-08    24  4   44  52
9-Nov-08    21  2   49  47
10-Nov-08   18  0   48  45
11-Nov-08   17  1   51  48
12-Nov-08   22  8   50  60
13-Nov-08   .   .   .   .
14-Nov-08   .   11  50  69
15-Nov-08   .   5   49  53
16-Nov-08   .   1   47  48
17-Nov-08   .   0   50  46
18-Nov-08   .   -3  53  46
19-Nov-08   23  2   49  49
20-Nov-08   26  1   48  48
21-Nov-08   26  -4  53  44
22-Nov-08   24  -4  56  43
23-Nov-08   25  0   51  47
24-Nov-08   30  2   50  51
25-Nov-08   34  1   50  48
26-Nov-08   34  1   49  50
27-Nov-08   32  2   48  50
28-Nov-08   35  2   48  50
29-Nov-08   33  2   47  49
30-Nov-08   33  1   49  51
1-Dec-08    33  -1  51  47
2-Dec-08    .   .   .   .
3-Dec-08    32  2   53  50
4-Dec-08    33  -4  52  44
5-Dec-08    32  -9  60  38
6-Dec-08    35  -4  57  44
7-Dec-08    36  -7  57  40
8-Dec-08    37  -1  55  46
9-Dec-08    44  6   50  57
10-Dec-08   40  -1  51  43
11-Dec-08   .   -3  54  44
12-Dec-08   39  -4  53  43
13-Dec-08   39  -1  55  46
14-Dec-08   42  7   48  59
15-Dec-08   .   -4  53  .
16-Dec-08   .   .   .   .
17-Dec-08   .   -5  58  44
18-Dec-08   32  -6  59  41
19-Dec-08   .   .   .   .
20-Dec-08   .   .   .   .
21-Dec-08   .   .   .   .
22-Dec-08   .   .   .   .
23-Dec-08   .   -4  66  .
24-Dec-08   .   2   57  .
25-Dec-08   .   -8  62  42
26-Dec-08   .   3   59  53
27-Dec-08   .   16  60  .
28-Dec-08   .   2   55  .
29-Dec-08   46  3   55  53
30-Dec-08   42  2   54  52
31-Dec-08   34  -5  58  40
1-Jan-09    41  -3  62  46
2-Jan-09    39  -1  55  48
3-Jan-09    42  -2  58  47
4-Jan-09    41  2   56  52
5-Jan-09    41  -4  57  46
6-Jan-09    40  -3  60  50
7-Jan-09    37  -2  57  44
8-Jan-09    42  -9  61  41
9-Jan-09    45  -5  62  45
10-Jan-09   44  -3  60  46
11-Jan-09   46  -4  61  46
12-Jan-09   47  -3  61  47
13-Jan-09   46  -6  60  44
14-Jan-09   42  -13 68  37
15-Jan-09   .   -18 71  33
16-Jan-09   .   .   .   .
17-Jan-09   .   .   .   .
18-Jan-09   .   .   .   .
19-Jan-09   84  -9  69  54
20-Jan-09   78  -11 71  47
21-Jan-09   64  -7  65  44
22-Jan-09   53  -1  57  47
23-Jan-09   51  0   56  48
24-Jan-09   54  -8  61  42
25-Jan-09   48  -13 68  37
26-Jan-09   43  -9  68  38
27-Jan-09   47  -8  64  40
28-Jan-09   46  -8  64  41
29-Jan-09   .   -6  62  42
30-Jan-09   .   -10 63  39
31-Jan-09   54  -8  67  41
1-Feb-09    55  2   57  50
2-Feb-09    54  -4  61  46
3-Feb-09    51  -8  65  41
4-Feb-09    49  -11 68  39
5-Feb-09    52  -10 68  41
6-Feb-09    51  -1  60  46
7-Feb-09    71  9   57  68
8-Feb-09    51  4   56  49
9-Feb-09    55  4   56  53
10-Feb-09   79  13  57  84
11-Feb-09   74  12  58  85
12-Feb-09   48  3   56  49
13-Feb-09   44  2   55  49
14-Feb-09   40  1   56  47
15-Feb-09   38  -1  56  45
16-Feb-09   40  -2  56  44
17-Feb-09   42  2   53  47
18-Feb-09   47  5   54  54
19-Feb-09   48  -7  58  40
20-Feb-09   43  -6  61  41
21-Feb-09   40  -4  59  43
22-Feb-09   38  -6  60  39
23-Feb-09   39  -7  62  39
24-Feb-09   41  -2  58  44
25-Feb-09   46  6   51  53
26-Feb-09   54  9   55  62
27-Feb-09   49  3   57  55
28-Feb-09   44  -3  57  44
1-Mar-09    38  -4  58  39
2-Mar-09    36  -7  60  38
3-Mar-09    36  -5  58  41
4-Mar-09    39  1   51  47
5-Mar-09    67  12  47  82
6-Mar-09    81  16  53  104
7-Mar-09    67  15  54  101
8-Mar-09    55  9   56  80
9-Mar-09    38  5   59  62
10-Mar-09   63  12  60  108
11-Mar-09   39  0   53  46
12-Mar-09   38  -2  60  47
13-Mar-09   41  0   55  50
14-Mar-09   48  4   52  56
15-Mar-09   57  8   47  66
16-Mar-09   54  11  43  72
17-Mar-09   58  15  41  94
18-Mar-09   .   13  44  76
19-Mar-09   39  6   42  56
20-Mar-09   41  1   48  52
21-Mar-09   45  8   44  63
22-Mar-09   45  11  41  70
23-Mar-09   45  6   44  63
24-Mar-09   48  12  40  69
25-Mar-09   40  13  47  70
26-Mar-09   35  10  47  58
27-Mar-09   .   11  45  67
28-Mar-09   .   .   .   .
29-Mar-09   .   .   .   .
30-Mar-09   .   .   .   .
31-Mar-09   .   .   .   .
1-Apr-09    .   .   .   .
2-Apr-09    .   .   .   .
3-Apr-09    .   .   .   .
4-Apr-09    .   .   .   .
5-Apr-09    .   .   .   .
6-Apr-09    .   .   .   .
7-Apr-09    .   .   .   .
8-Apr-09    .   .   .   .
9-Apr-09    .   .   .   .
10-Apr-09   .   .   .   .
11-Apr-09   .   .   .   .
12-Apr-09   .   .   .   .
13-Apr-09   .   .   .   .
14-Apr-09   .   .   .   .
15-Apr-09   .   .   .   .
16-Apr-09   30  12  38  128
17-Apr-09   36  16  32  183
18-Apr-09   .   19  35  294
19-Apr-09   .   14  50  142
20-Apr-09   29  9   51  89
21-Apr-09   27  6   48  72
22-Apr-09   29  9   41  95
23-Apr-09   .   13  35  140
24-Apr-09   .   22  36  457
25-Apr-09   .   24  39  532
26-Apr-09   .   25  38  541
27-Apr-09   .   23  42  497
28-Apr-09   .   15  61  168
29-Apr-09   .   11  55  106
30-Apr-09   .   .   .   .
1-May-09    28  16  59  154
2-May-09    .   .   .   .
3-May-09    .   .   .   .
4-May-09    .   .   .   .
5-May-09    .   .   .   .
6-May-09    .   16  52  169
7-May-09    29  18  53  276
8-May-09    13  20  60  270
9-May-09    28  15  51  151
10-May-09   22  13  46  134
11-May-09   20  14  40  113
12-May-09   16  15  34  167
13-May-09   18  17  54  219
14-May-09   24  19  50  278
15-May-09   .   17  51  .
16-May-09   .   16  58  .
17-May-09   .   12  39  .
18-May-09   .   15  35  .
19-May-09   .   20  31  .
20-May-09   .   24  28  386
21-May-09   26  24  35  433
22-May-09   .   24  44  441
23-May-09   .   23  42  407
24-May-09   .   25  47  448
25-May-09   .   20  36  290
26-May-09   .   23  48  394
27-May-09   .   26  59  493
28-May-09   .   18  59  238
29-May-09   .   19  47  301
30-May-09   .   21  38  330
31-May-09   .   20  35  281
1-Jun-09    .   .   .   .
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try to fit a [distributed lag model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lag) that has the form

$$
Y_{i}=\alpha + \sum_{l=0}^{K}\beta_{j}x_{t-l} + \text{other predictors} +\epsilon_{i}
$$

where $K$ is the maximum lag and $x$ is a predictor. This is just fitted using a multiple linear regression (as you have already said in your question). So the coefficient $\beta_{1}$ would estimate the effect of $x_{t-1}$ of the day before on $Y_{t}$. In essence, multiple lags of the predictors are included in the model simultaneously. This obviously has the problem that the lagged predictors are highly correlated (autocorrelation).

To create the lagged variables, you may use the `embed` function in `R`:

```
x <- 1:10
lag <- 3

embed(c(rep(NA, lag), x), lag)

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]    1   NA   NA
 [3,]    2    1   NA
 [4,]    3    2    1
 [5,]    4    3    2
 [6,]    5    4    3
 [7,]    6    5    4
 [8,]    7    6    5
 [9,]    8    7    6
[10,]    9    8    7
[11,]   10    9    8
```

A more advanced method are [polynomial distributed lag models](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v43/i08/paper). It has the same basic formula as above, but the impulse-response function is forced to lie on a polynomial of degree $q$ ([link](http://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/116237/2/sjart_st0065.pdf) to a paper for Stata):

$$
\beta_{i} = a_{0} + a_{1}i + a_{2}i^2 +\ldots+a_{q}i^q
$$
where $q$ is the degree of the polynomial and $i$ the lag length. Another formulation is
$$
\beta_{i} = a_{0} + \sum_{j=1}^{q}a_{j}f_{j}(i)
$$
Where $f_{j}(i)$ is a polynomial of degree $j$ in the lag length $i$.

You could use the `dlnm` packge in `R` to fit distributed polynomial lag models ([here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlnm/vignettes/dlnmOverview.pdf) are a lot of examples).

Because you are dealing with meteorological variables, you could try to fit a generalized additive model (GAM) with splines, allowing for a more flexible modelling of the predictors. You could, for example fit a spline for the calendar time and polynomial distributed lag models of the meteorological variables. [Here](http://www3.nd.edu/~mclark19/learn/GAMS.pdf) is an introduction.

Comment: Appreciate so much for your kind help! I will try them. Thanks a lot!!